# I am wanting to run a DOS cmd to copy an exe file from another directory and then run the executable using a wildcard but it's not working

Tags: dos

Here is the cmd in which it does copy the file but does not execute it afterwards:

```
 copy /v /z "\\cardinal-9547e3\Active Production\Isotrac Online*.exe" %tmp%
 %tmp\Isotrac Online*.exe
```

Comment: You can't use a wildcard to run the EXE.  You must use the *actual* file name.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't think so ;)

Comment: @alfasin: Ah, but your solution is iterating through the individual .exe files, good sir.  You're using the *actual file names.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey LOL you're right :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
copy /v /z "\\cardinal-9547e3\Active Production\Isotrac Online*.exe" %tmp%
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b %tmp\Isotrac Online*.exe') DO %%G
```

Comment: Alfasin i've tried your cmd but it tells me "the syntax of the command is incorrect"

Comment: @Drew: The idea here is correct: you need to iterate through the individual .EXE files.  Fix the syntax problem, and you should be good to go.

Comment: @Drew change `DO %%G` to `DO @echo %%G` and see what's printed

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if we need the quotes in `('dir /b %tmp\Isotrac Online*.exe')` - but I can't test it right now - sorry!

Comment: Thanks Alfasin...i'll mess around with it and see what happens. If it ends up working i'll be sure to rep you!

Comment: I've messed around with the script and made many changes but still can't get it to work. I keep getting the error "the syntax of the command is incorrect". But what is incorrect about it?

Comment: I don't typically use DOS commands much which is why i'm stuck. Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: @Drew run the "echo" thing I wrote above and then try to run the same command manually, maybe the command that you're trying to run requires parameters

Comment: I ran the echo cmd and got "DO is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: @Drew did you do `@echo` ?

Comment: Yes sir...DO @echo %%G

Comment: That's really weird, all there is left is to go over the spec and see if you're having some kind of "corner-case" like encoding issues:  http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html